# Wordpress menu with Boostrap, sub menu which have menus inside acts as a link instead showing menus on mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Problem: on desktop version menu shows sub menus but it also have a link. so if I hover it shows sub menus and if I click on it, it acts as a link. but on mobile when I click on menu instead showing sub menus it acts as a link on the click and I'm unable to open sub menus.

Images are here. [first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwJRt.jpg)
[second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enS8K.jpg). so menu Program have menu Films List. on first image it's not opened on second it's.

So the question is: how to force mobile version website to show sub menus on parent click instead acting as a link. 
please ask if something isn't clear.

Comment: Show us some code

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a design answer. "User experience," if you prefer.

I suggest changing the design of your mobile app to match user expectations. I do not believe that I have EVER seen a drop-down menu on a mobile app before. (And I've seen a few apps in my time!)

I have seen many accordion menus used to handle this function. I recommend this approach.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

An alternate style sheet can be used for mobile, or a sub domain approach: your choice.

All the best!

Comment: I also found this tutorial on the Web, if you haven't done bootstrap accordion menus before. Note that I haven't used this myself, but it seems straightforward. http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php